# Converting class-based JS useState array to TypeScript Hook problem

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, react-hooks

I've been working with React / TypeScript for a few days and am teaching myself by doing a small project. As part of that I am currently converting some class based code into hooks.

I have the following (JS) class based code that I don't know how to convert to use in a hook with TypeScript:

```
this.setState({
  data: [
    ...this.state.data,
    {
      chx: chx,
      type: type,
      bin: bin,
      ascii: ascii,
    },
  ],
});
```

In my hook based equivalent I know that I would use `setData();` for a simple state. But, how do I convert the example above? My attempt (below) is clearly wrong, as I'm getting the error: `Type '{ chx: unknown; type: string; bin: string; ascii: string; }' is not assignable to type 'never'.` But I'm stuck for what I should do next to try and resolve this:

```
setData([
  ...data,
  {
    chx: chx,
    type: type,
    bin: bin,
    ascii: ascii,
  }
])
```

### Update

I got this working by changing my useState declaration from:

```
const [ data, setData ] = useState([]);
```

to

```
const [ data, setData ] = useState<any>([]); //{type: read/write/notify/error, bin: 8 int binary, ascii: ASCII Value}
```

However, I realise this just defeats the object of using TypeScript. So, my next move based on @tomleb3 answer was to create an interface for `data` like so:

```
const [ data, setData ] = useState<DataType>([]); //{type: read/write/notify/error, bin: 8 int binary, ascii: ASCII Value}
  
  interface DataType{
    chx: any,
    bin: string,
    type: string,
    ascii: string
  }
```

but this gives an error:

> Argument of type 'never[]' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'DataType | (() => DataType)'.   Type 'never[]' is not assignable to
> type '() => DataType'.
> Type 'never[]' provides no match for the signature '(): DataType'.

I don't know how to progress from here as removing the `[]` useState declaration then pushes the error down to wherever I use a `setData()` call with the following error:

> Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'SetStateAction<DataType | undefined>'.   Type 'any[]' is not
> assignable to type '(prevState: DataType | undefined) => DataType |
> undefined'.

Comment: Well if your state type is ultimately an array of `DataType` objects, then the proper syntax is `const [ data, setData ] = useState<DataType[]>([]);`

Comment: @tomleb3 Of course. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are receiving is a Typescript error, not a React error.
Your code is perfectly fine, but when working with Typescript we need to type our states just as well as everything else.

Which can look like this for example:

```js
interface State {
   key1: string,
   key2: number,
   key3: boolean,
}

function myComponent() {
   const [state, setState] = useState<State>({
      key1: 'test',
      key2: 42,
      key3: false,
   })
}
```

This allows Typescript to know the structure of your state and thus enabling it to apply the relevant type guards and restrictions.

Comment: Thanks. I assumed that was the case but at this stage I'm trying to have an open mind rather than make assumptions that could cause me problems later.

Comment: Please see my updated question. I've tried adding an interface but this has led to other errors. Thanks.

Comment: Phill / tomleb3 - can you discuss between you whether the question update represents a new question? Update sections to questions tend to create what we call "chameleon questions" that are forever metamorphosing into a new state, and it places a demand on an answer author to respond to a sequence of questions rather than just one.

Comment: If it doubt, err on the side of caution and - please Phill - ask a new question. Remember that the purpose of this platform is to help future readers - helping the question author is part of the process, but somewhat incidental. One thing to consider is: are the two problems highly related, or can they stand alone? If the latter is true then perhaps a new question is the way to go.

Comment: I agree, will update my answer accordingly if the question gets updated.

Comment: @halfer I agree, however it seemed -to me- that this was just helping push the question along to the answer that I was in need of from the start. I thought I was supplying extra info here and didn't personally see this as changing the question. But, I'll certainly keep it in mind next time.